# Converting hindi/arabic charset from a pdf file to a mobi file

Tags: pdf, type-conversion, kindle

I am creating an online service and I have absolutely no idea on where to even start on multilingual pdf to mobi file conversion. I have created an app for english language and that is pretty easy but the problem with the pdf and multibyte charsets is that they are interpreted as images which means that they are not interpreted as words in mobi file format.

Is there a way/online service/api/code to do/implement this? Any windows application that can do this on file to file basis would be fine as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own plugin for this as there is no support for this in the market. 
However, you can convert it using a custom map of letters which would mean that each image is first read by ocr and then that is used to find a utf equivalent.